# Magento - attempts to connect through unix socket despite remote ip set in local.xml

Tags: mysql, magento

```
 <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[10.1.39.35]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[db_magento]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
```

My local.xml file configuration is shown above.
I am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Trace:
#0 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php(45): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql->getConnection(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Cache.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Cache->getAllOptions()
#11 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(459): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#12 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1101): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#13 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(404): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#14 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#15 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(359): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#16 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#17 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/ecosmart/public_html/e-nrg.com/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

I have been looking on the internet, and I can't find someone with the same problem as this = everyone says that this occurs when they are running their local mysql on a different port. I am not, I am running a seperate server with a database that is networked through an internal network.

Does anyone know a workaround to stop magento using the MYSQL socket connection and force it to use the TCP protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you clean your cache? `rm -rf var/cache`

Comment: Yes I tried that, thanks for the comment. I'm afraid i've failed to get it working. It was magento 1.4.2.0 on a php 5.3 server

Answer (score 1):

Here is the posts with answers that helped me to solve similar problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/125686/mysql-fails-to-start-after-upgrade-installation-etc
https://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2857/